# Regex for avoiding input of numbers only (input without any other characters)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a Regex which is like:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

which is a Regex for alphanumeric with at least 1 number and 1 character.

But I am trying to have a Regex which avoids the input of Numbers. i.e. if only numbers are the only input for the field then it should be rejected...

So what sort of regex i should use?

**EDIT:**
My required input could be 'abc111','abc 111','abc@111','abc @111'

MY NOT REQUIRED inputs are '111',' sdf '(spaces should not be allowed on left and right side)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? If you only input numbers the regex will fail.

Comment: @stema Yes u R guessing right.., If i input only numbers i.e. 1 or 2 or 99 etc.. they it should reject but if I input the values like aa11, aa 11 etc and other special characters

Comment: Would it not be more user-friendly to just remove the spaces yourself? Why would that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/[^0-9]/
```

At least one not-numeric.

### Edit: extra question posed in comments

If you also want to remove whitespace, either use the [Javascript trim() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) (easiest!), or use the RegExp to capture everything but the whitespace:

```
/^\s(.*[^0-9].*)\s$)`
```

Explanation:

```
/^         // Start of the line (no characters before)
 \s        // Any whitespace (thus right after the start of the line)
 (         // Start capturing group
   .*      // Any character (zero or more)
   [^0-9]  // A non-numeric character so at least one is present, as required
   .*      // Any character (zero or more)
  )        // End capturing group
  \s       // Any whitespace (thus right before the end of the line)
$/         // End of the line (no characters after this)
```

Comment: could u explain me the differentiation in the answer given by u and @Sergey Kudnavtsev

Comment: Eh, mine was first? No, his answer adds the `+`, which means 'atleast one or more'. It is needed if there are other elements in your regexp, for example `/a[0-9]b/` means  "start with a, then one digit, then a b", where `/a[0-9]+b/` means  "start with a, then at least one (but possibly more) digits, then a b". In this example, both solutions are equivalent, and mine is shorter ;)

Comment: Also, he included the `()` around to group (and capture) the elements in the regexp, probably because you did the same thing in your question. Unless you explicitly need a capturing group (working with `\1 \2 \3` later on), you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Also how to trim byitself the leading and trainling whitespaces

Comment: @OMTheEternity: Really both solutions are equivalent in your context, and Konerak had shorter version. As Konerak also added extra parts for whitespaces, I'd suggest you use his solution.

Comment: @Konerak The regex u gave me is not allowing the characters also, I want the characters, characters+numbers, characters+numbers+special characters, characters+special characters, numbers+special characters, u r expression is not allowing me anything

Comment: Can you be more specific than "*not allowing me anything*"? Does the small expression work? Does the big one work? What input work, what don't, what should, what shouldn't?

Comment: @Konerak Please chek the editted question I have mentioned what must be allowed and what should not

Comment: Aha, but that differs from your original remark here, you said: *how to trim byitself the leading and trainling whitespaces* -> that would mean the user is allowed to type them, and the application removes them. Which is btw much more user-friendly than forbidding them... are you sure you wouldn't rather do a trim before the regexp?

Comment: You need what? To remove whitespace, or to reject?

Answer (score 1):

What about the simplest one - `([^0-9]+)` ?